# Returning Replies to multiple Teams chat messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have successfully used:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id-for-teams}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}/replies](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bgroup-id-for-teams%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages/%7Bmessage-id%7D/replies)

...to return the set of replies to one message.  I was hoping I could add a wildcard to the message-id field but, the help for this script says it is limited to one item.

Could anyone suggest a way i could return replies for a complete set of messages in a channel?

Comment: This API returns the replies to a specific message based on message ID, What do you mean by replies for all messages in channel? A message is known by it's message id and later you fetch the replies, if you want all messages in channel you can use [List channel Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API to get all messages later you can extract the message id from it and use it in list channel message reply API

Comment: Sorry..overlooked your reply.  Yes..i thought about this, but I am a largely non-technical user and that would require more scripting skills than i currently have.  I had hoped there might be a single bulk call that I could enter a channel reference and get all traffic back. Is there a simple bit of code that nests one API call inside another?